# Website accordion (expanding content) causing parallax images to jump but only on mobile (iOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, parallax, mobile-website

```js
function initializeParallax(clip) {
  var parallax = clip.querySelectorAll('*[parallax]');
  var parallaxDetails = [];
  var sticky = false;

  // Edge requires a transform on the document body and a fixed position element
  // in order for it to properly render the parallax effect as you scroll.
  // See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/5084491/
  if (getComputedStyle(document.body).transform == 'none')
    document.body.style.transform = 'translateZ(0)';
  var fixedPos = document.createElement('div');
  fixedPos.style.position = 'fixed';
  fixedPos.style.top = '0';
  fixedPos.style.width = '1px';
  fixedPos.style.height = '1px';
  fixedPos.style.zIndex = 1;
  document.body.insertBefore(fixedPos, document.body.firstChild);

  for (var i = 0; i < parallax.length; i++) {
    var elem = parallax[i];
    var container = elem.parentNode;
    if (getComputedStyle(container).overflow != 'visible') {
      console.error('Need non-scrollable container to apply perspective for', elem);
      continue;
    }
    if (clip && container.parentNode != clip) {
      console.warn('Currently we only track a single overflow clip, but elements from multiple clips found.', elem);
    }
    var clip = container.parentNode;
    if (getComputedStyle(clip).overflow == 'visible') {
      console.error('Parent of sticky container should be scrollable element', elem);
    }
    // TODO(flackr): optimize to not redo this for the same clip/container.
    var perspectiveElement;
    if (sticky || getComputedStyle(clip).webkitOverflowScrolling) {
      sticky = true;
      perspectiveElement = container;
    } else {
      perspectiveElement = clip;
      container.style.transformStyle = 'preserve-3d';
    }
    perspectiveElement.style.perspectiveOrigin = 'bottom right';
    perspectiveElement.style.perspective = '1px';
    if (sticky)
      elem.style.position = '-webkit-sticky';
    if (sticky)
      elem.style.top = '0';
    elem.style.transformOrigin = 'bottom right';

    // Find the previous and next elements to parallax between.
    var previousCover = parallax[i].previousElementSibling;
    while (previousCover && previousCover.hasAttribute('parallax'))
      previousCover = previousCover.previousElementSibling;
    var nextCover = parallax[i].nextElementSibling;
    while (nextCover && !nextCover.hasAttribute('parallax-cover'))
      nextCover = nextCover.nextElementSibling;

    parallaxDetails.push({
      'node': parallax[i],
      'top': parallax[i].offsetTop,
      'sticky': !!sticky,
      'nextCover': nextCover,
      'previousCover': previousCover
    });
  }

  // Add a scroll listener to hide perspective elements when they should no
  // longer be visible.
  clip.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < parallaxDetails.length; i++) {
      var container = parallaxDetails[i].node.parentNode;
      var previousCover = parallaxDetails[i].previousCover;
      var nextCover = parallaxDetails[i].nextCover;
      var parallaxStart = previousCover ? (previousCover.offsetTop + previousCover.offsetHeight) : 0;
      var parallaxEnd = nextCover ? nextCover.offsetTop : container.offsetHeight;
      var threshold = 200;
      var visible = parallaxStart - threshold - clip.clientHeight < clip.scrollTop &&
        parallaxEnd + threshold > clip.scrollTop;
      // FIXME: Repainting the images while scrolling can cause jank.
      // For now, keep them all.
      // var display = visible ? 'block' : 'none'
      var display = 'block';
      if (parallaxDetails[i].node.style.display != display)
        parallaxDetails[i].node.style.display = display;
    }
  });
  window.addEventListener('resize', onResize.bind(null, parallaxDetails));
  onResize(parallaxDetails);
  for (var i = parallax.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    parallax[i].parentNode.insertBefore(parallax[i], parallax[i].parentNode.firstChild);
  }

  console.log("initialized!");
}

function onResize(details) {
  for (var i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
    var container = details[i].node.parentNode;

    var clip = container.parentNode;
    var previousCover = details[i].previousCover;
    var nextCover = details[i].nextCover;
    var rate = details[i].node.getAttribute('parallax');

    var parallaxStart = previousCover ? (previousCover.offsetTop + previousCover.offsetHeight) : 0;
    var scrollbarWidth = details[i].sticky ? 0 : clip.offsetWidth - clip.clientWidth;
    var parallaxElem = details[i].sticky ? container : clip;
    var height = details[i].node.offsetHeight;
    var depth = 0;
    if (rate) {
      depth = 1 - (1 / rate);
    } else {
      var parallaxEnd = nextCover ? nextCover.offsetTop : container.offsetHeight;
      depth = (height - parallaxEnd + parallaxStart) / (height - clip.clientHeight);
    }
    if (details[i].sticky)
      depth = 1.0 / depth;

    var scale = 1.0 / (1.0 - depth);

    // The scrollbar is included in the 'bottom right' perspective origin.
    var dx = scrollbarWidth * (scale - 1);
    // Offset for the position within the container.
    var dy = details[i].sticky ?
      // original was clip.scrollHeight? but it gave issues only for mobile b/c
      // details[i].sticky was true
      -(container.scrollHeight - parallaxStart - height) * (1 - scale) :
      (parallaxStart - depth * (height - clip.clientHeight)) * scale;
    console.log(container, dy);
    console.log("container.scrollHeight", container.scrollHeight);
    console.log("parallaxStart", parallaxStart);
    console.log("height", height);
    console.log("scale", scale);
    console.log("parallaxStart", parallaxStart);
    console.log("depth", depth);
    console.log("height", height);
    console.log("clip.clientHeight", clip.clientHeight);
    console.log("scale", scale);
    console.log(details[i].sticky);

    details[i].node.style.transform = 'scale(' + (1 - depth) + ') translate3d(' + dx + 'px, ' + dy + 'px, ' + depth + 'px)';
  }
}




window.onload = function() {
  // setTimeout(function() {

  // get all lazy image elements
  const lazy_images = document.querySelectorAll('.lazy-image');

  lazy_images.forEach(function(lazy_image) {

    const imgLargeSrc = lazy_image.dataset.large;

    // get small/lazy image
    const small = lazy_image.querySelector('.img-small');
    if (small == null) {
      const imgSmall = new Image();
      imgSmall.src = "//images.weserv.nl/?url=elenaariza.com" +
        imgLargeSrc + "&w=25&fit=cover&output=png";
      imgSmall.alt = imgLargeSrc;
      imgSmall.classList.add("img-small");
      imgSmall.onload = function() {
        imgSmall.classList.add("loaded");
      }
      lazy_image.appendChild(imgSmall);
    }


    const imgLarge = new Image();
    imgLarge.src = imgLargeSrc;
    imgLarge.onload = function() {
      // mark large image as loaded
      imgLarge.classList.add('loaded');
    };

    // add large image to the lazy_image element
    lazy_image.appendChild(imgLarge);
  });
  // },0);
};
```

```css
/** Reset some basic elements */
/** body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, hr, dl, dd, ol, ul, figure { margin: 0; padding: 0; } */

/** Basic styling */
p:last-child, ol:last-child, ul:last-child { margin-bottom: 0 !important; margin-right: 0 !important; }

html { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }

body { font: 400 16px/1.5 "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #432814; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-font-feature-settings: "kern" 1; -moz-font-feature-settings: "kern" 1; -o-font-feature-settings: "kern" 1; font-feature-settings: "kern" 1; font-kerning: normal; background-color: #edece8; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; display: flex; flex-direction: column; }

/** Set `margin-bottom` to maintain vertical rhythm */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, ul, ol, dl, figure { margin-bottom: 20px; }

p { text-align: justify; text-justify: inter-word; margin-bottom: 20px; }

/** Images */
img { vertical-align: middle; margin-bottom: 10px; }

/** Lists */
ul, ol { margin-left: 40px; }

li > ul, li > ol { margin-bottom: 0; }

/** Headings */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-weight: 400; }

/** Wrapper */
.wrapper { max-width: -webkit-calc(1000px - (40px * 2)); max-width: calc(1000px - (40px * 2)); width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; padding-right: 40px; padding-left: 40px; }

.page-content .wrapper { padding-top: calc(max(40px, 4vw)); padding-bottom: calc(max(40px, 4vw)); }

.site-footer .wrapper { padding-top: 40px; padding-bottom: 40px; }

.site-header .wrapper { position: relative; padding-top: 18.3333333333px; padding-bottom: 13.3333333333px; }

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { .wrapper { max-width: -webkit-calc(1000px - (40px * 1.5)); max-width: calc(1000px - (40px * 1.5)); padding-right: 30px; padding-left: 30px; } }

/** Page content */
.page-content { position: relative; flex: 1 0 auto; }

.page-heading { font-size: 20px; }

/** Posts */
.post-header { margin-bottom: 40px; }

.post-title { font-size: 36px; letter-spacing: 0px; line-height: 1; }

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) { .post-title { font-size: 30px; } }

.post-content h2 { font-size: 32px; }

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) { .post-content h2 { font-size: 26px; } }

.post-content h3 { font-size: 24px; }

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) { .post-content h3 { font-size: 22px; } }

.post-content h4 { font-size: 20px; }

.post-content h4.with-description { margin-bottom: 0; }

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) { .post-content h4 { font-size: 18px; } }

.post-content h5 { font-size: 16px; text-indent: 25px; }

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) { .post-content h5 { font-size: 14px; } }

.post-content p { font-size: calc(max(1.1vw, 16px)); }

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) { .post-content p { font-size: 16px; } }

/** Parallax */

.viewport { height: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; position: relative; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; scroll-behavior: smooth; transform-style: preserve-3d; perspective: 1px; }

.scene { height: calc(min(90vw, 80vh)); }

.scene:not(.solid) { box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5); }

.parallax > img { object-position: 50% 50%; box-sizing: border-box; height: calc(min(105vw, 85vh)); margin-bottom: calc(max(-105vw, -85vh)); object-fit: cover; top: 0px; min-width: 100%; width: 100%; }

/** Lazy image loading */

.lazy-image { min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; }

.lazy-image > img { position: absolute; -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-out; -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-out; transition: opacity 1s ease-out; object-fit: cover; opacity: 0; }

.lazy-image > img.loaded { opacity: 1; }

/** */

.header.parallax > img { height: 100vh; margin-bottom: -100vh; }

.header.scene { height: 90vh; }

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { .header.parallax > img { height: 110vh; margin-bottom: -110vh; } .header.scene { height: 85vh; } }

.page-header.parallax > img { height: 60vh; margin-bottom: -60vh; }

.page-header.scene { height: 50vh; }

.solid { z-index: 1; position: relative; height: auto; display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-items: flex-start; min-height: 40vh; background-color: #fdfcfa; }

.img-small { filter: blur(20px); transform: scale(1); }

#btn-back-to-top { position: fixed; bottom: 40px; right: 40px; opacity: 0; transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out; z-index: 10; height: 52px; width: 52px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: #e67422; box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px #e67422; visibility: hidden; }

#btn-back-to-top i.fa-arrow-up { color: white; }

div.toggle-content { diplay: flex; margin: 20px; font-size: 1.1rem; }

div.toggle-content > ul { border: none; margin-bottom: 25px; }

div.toggle-content h2 { font-size: 28px; }

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) { div.toggle-content h2 { font-size: 24px; } }

div.toggle-content h3 { margin-bottom: 10px; }

.toggle-wrapper h2 { align-items: center; color: #e67422; text-transform: none; font-weight: 300; cursor: pointer; transition: .2s; }

.toggle-wrapper p { line-height: 1.45; position: relative; overflow: hidden; max-height: 250px; will-change: max-height; contain: layout; display: block; opacity: 1; transform: translate(0, 0); padding: 0 40px 0 2 5px; transition: .3s opacity, .6s max-height; hyphens: auto; z-index: 2; }

.toggle-wrapper { width: 100%; display: flex; max-width: 700px; margin: auto; text-align: center; align-items: center; }

.toggle-wrapper ul { width: 100%; text-align: left; }

.transition, p, ul li i:before, ul li i:after { transition: all 0.3s; }

.toggle-wrapper .no-select, .toggle-wrapper h2 { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; -webkit-touch-callout: none; user-select: none; }

.toggle-wrapper ul { list-style: none; perspective: 900; padding: 0; margin: 0; }

.toggle-wrapper > ul > li { position: relative; overflow: hidden; padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 1px #A096A0; border-bottom: 0px; border-style: solid none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; }

.toggle-wrapper > ul > li:last-of-type { padding-bottom: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #A096A0; margin-bottom: 10px; }

.toggle-wrapper > ul > li > i { position: absolute; transform: translate(-6px, 0); margin-top: 2.2rem; right: 15px; }

.toggle-wrapper > ul > li > i:before, .toggle-wrapper > ul > li > i:after { content: ""; position: absolute; background-color: #e67422; width: 3px; height: 9px; }

.toggle-wrapper ul li i:before { transform: translate(-2px, 0) rotate(45deg); }

.toggle-wrapper ul li i:after { transform: translate(2px, 0) rotate(-45deg); }

.toggle-wrapper ul li input[type=checkbox] { position: absolute; cursor: pointer; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 1; opacity: 0; touch-action: manipulation; }

.toggle-wrapper ul li input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div h2 { color: #432814; margin-bottom: 0px; }

.toggle-wrapper ul li input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div :not(h2) { /*margin-top: 0;*/ max-height: 0; transition: .3s; opacity: 0; margin-bottom: 0px !important; margin-top: 0px !important; /*transform: translate(0, 50%);*/ }

.toggle-wrapper ul li input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ i:before { transform: translate(2px, 0) rotate(45deg); }

.toggle-wrapper ul li input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ i:after { transform: translate(-2px, 0) rotate(-45deg); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<body>
  <div class="viewport">

    <!-- {% include header.html %} -->

    <div class="page-content parallax-container">

      <div class="parallax page-header lazy-image" data-large="https://elenaariza.com/img/Elena-Ariza-black-and-white-by-Anastasia-Chernyavsky.jpg" parallax="0.7">
        <img src="//images.weserv.nl/?url=elenaariza.com/img/Elena-Ariza-black-and-white-by-Anastasia-Chernyavsky.jpg&w=25&fit=cover&output=png" class="img-small loaded">
      </div>
      <div class="scene page-header"></div>

      <div class="scene solid">

        <article class="post wrapper">

          <div class="post-content">
            <div class="toggle-wrapper">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" checked>
                  <i></i>
                  <div class="toggle-content">
                    <h2>Concerti</h2>
                    <ul>
  <li>Bloch: Schelomo Rhapsodie Hébraïque</li>
  <li>Dvorak: Cello Concerto in B Minor</li>
  <li>Elgar: Cello Concerto in E Minor, Op. 85</li>
  <li>Haydn: Cello Concerto No. 1 in C Major</li>
  <li>Haydn: Cello Concerto No. 2 in D Major</li>
  <li>Herbert: Cello Concerto No. 2 in E Minor, Op. 30</li>
  <li>Lalo: Cello Concerto in D Minor</li>
  <li>Prokofiev: Sinfonia Concertante, Op. 125</li>
  <li>Saint-Saens: Cello Concerto No. 1, Op. 33</li>
  <li>Schumann: Cello Concerto in A minor, Op. 129</li>
  <li>Tchaikovsky: Variations on a Rococo Theme, Op. 33</li>
</ul>

    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <i></i>
      <div class="toggle-content">
      <h2>Sonatas / Works with Piano</h2>

      <ul>
  <li>Bach: Sonata for viola da gamba in D major BWV 1028</li>
  <li>Barber: Cello Sonata Op. 6</li>
  <li>Beethoven: Cello Sonata No. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5</li>
  <li>Beethoven: 7 Variations on “Bei Männern”, WoO 46</li>
  <li>Boccherini: Cello Sonata in A Major, G. 4</li>
  <li>Boulanger: Three Pieces for Cello and Piano</li>
  <li>Brahms: Cello Sonata No. 1 in E Minor, Op. 38</li>
  <li>Brahms: Cello Sonata No. 2 in F Major, Op. 99</li>
  <li>Bridge: Four Pieces for Cello and Piano</li>
  <li>Carter: Cello Sonata</li>
  <li>Cassadó: Requiebros</li>
  <li>Chopin: Introduction and Polonaise Brillante in C Major, Op. 3</li>
  <li>Chopin: Cello Sonata in G minor, Op. 65</li>
  <li>Davidoff: At the Fountain Op. 20, No. 2</li>
  <li>Debussy: Cello Sonata in D Minor</li>
  <li>Franck: Sonata in A major for Violin and Piano</li>
  <li>Francoeur: Sonata for Cello and Piano in E Major</li>
  <li>Grieg: Cello Sonata in A minor, Op. 36</li>
  <li>Janacek: Pohadka for Cello and Piano</li>
  <li>Locatelli: Sonata for Cello and Piano</li>
  <li>Mendelssohn: Cello Sonata No. 2 in D major, Op. 58</li>
  <li>Mykola Lysenko: Elegy for Cello and Piano</li>
  <li>Pärt: Fratres</li>
  <li>Piazzolla: Le Grand Tango</li>
  <li>Popper: Elfentanz, Op. 39</li>
  <li>Prokofiev: Cello Sonata in C major, Op. 119</li>
  <li>Rachmaninov: Cello Sonata, Op. 19</li>
  <li>Schumann: Adagio and Allegro, Op. 70</li>
  <li>Schumann: Fantasiestücke, Op. 73</li>
  <li>Shostakovich: Sonata for Cello and Piano in D Minor, Op. 40</li>
  <li>Schubert: Arpeggione Sonata in A Minor</li>
</ul>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

        </article>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- {% include footer.html %} -->

  </div>

</body>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    initializeParallax(document.querySelector('.viewport'));
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Newbie to stackoverflow here, so please let me know if there are any issues with this question.

I'm encountering an issue where expanding the accordion on my website causes the parallax background image to jump downwards, because the website content height changes. However, what puzzles me is that this issue only happens on iOS (both Safari and Chrome apps). The parallax seems to be fine on Android and both Safari and Chrome on Mac.

I've implemented "performative parallax" that is described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/performant-parallaxing/).

[GIF of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEFTI.gif)

The actual website is accessible [here](https://elenaariza.com/repertoire/). Code hosted [on Github](https://github.com/dawnstar63/new-website-2021).

I'm not very experienced in HTML/CSS and/or JS, but I've fiddled around with the parallax JS/CSS to no avail.
I've also seen similar issues discussed [here](https://divi.help/threads/accordion-module-shortens-the-parallax-background-image-height.5621/) and [here](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/3302), but neither solution fixed the issue (or I may have done something incorrectly).

Thank you so much for your help!

EDIT (also in comment): Came up with a temporary solution – literally just added the code below to the JS. I know it's a hacky workaround, but works surprisingly well.

```
// create an Observer instance
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  // console.log('Body height changed:', entries[0].target.clientHeight);
  onResize(parallaxDetails);
});

// start observing a DOM node
resizeObserver.observe(document.getElementsByClassName("parallax-container")[0]);
```

Comment: Stack Snippet, please :)

Comment: added code snippet! (more like a code dump, but tried to minimize as much as possible)

EDIT: just confirmed on mobile (iOS) that the issue is reproduced

Comment: UPDATE/bump: still couldn't figure out the core issue… I created a workaround by adding a ResizeObserver to the webpage content, and calling the parallax onResize() function every time the content height changes. I expected the movement/scroll to be stodgy, but this surprisingly worked well… still would be nice to figure out the root cause though.